# Trigger Window.addEventListenner on JS testing

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine

I Have a callback method on window scroll event but i can't simulate it on my JS tests. Im using Karma, Jasmine and Enzyme.

im trying like this...

`spyOn(window, 'scrollTop').and.returnValue(100);`

But the callback is not being triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Define window as a global variable and return this function in it and remove the injector for window in beforeEach.

```
var window = {
    scrollTop: function() {
        return <value>
        } 
    }
```